# Typescript MQTT Broker

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I want to build a MQTT Broker in Typescript with angular. I have tried some examples, but always get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: http.createServer is not a function
```

Here the simple example i am trying to run at the moment:

```
var http = require('http');
var port2 = 9000;

http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello there, world\n');
}).listen(port2);

console.log("Listening on port " + port2);
```

Has anyone an idea where i get this error from, or an other example broker I could try?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What environment is this code running in? Is it in a browser or on Node.js?

Comment: Im uising node.js in the latest version.

Comment: What is the type of object is http? Is it maybe a promise?

Comment: http is a npm object, which I installed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is probably being run in the browser while using Node.js APIs.

A Node error would look like this:
[image: Node Error]

While a browser error looks more similar to what you refer to in the question.
[image: Browser Error]

The snippet I've run for both of these tests is as follows:

```
var http = {};
var port2 = 9000;

http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello there, world\n');
}).listen(port2);

console.log("Listening on port " + port2);
```

Your provided snippet works OK when run on the latest Nodejs docker image with node.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in this case the compiler throws the error: Property 'createServer' does not exist on type '{}'. Do you have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please run your snippet but insert a console.log(window), before calling `http.createServer`?

Comment: Output: Window {window: Window, self: Window, document: document, name: "", location: Location, …}

Comment: This means that your code is run on the browser and not inside Node.js, since `window` is a global object only available in browsers. `http` is a native node module, which means it doesn't exist in the browser but, if you run your snippet file with node, you will see it works fine. You might find more information here https://nodejs.dev/learn/differences-between-nodejs-and-the-browser.

Comment: But I need this Broker in the Backend of my Browser Applikation. Is there no way I can reach this?

Comment: You probably need to use a different platform than angular to create a mqtt broker. Something that runs on nodejs and not in the browser. If you have experience with angular, nest js might be a good fit, a good example of an mqtt broker might be here https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/mqtt. Or you can build your own using various nodejs guides that can be found on the internet.